# Input data into table and auto sort

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, html-table

I am trying to figure out this simple problem. I want to have the user be able to input data and then the data automatically sorts in ascending order to whatever has already been submitted in the table. I'm stuck on the auto-sorting part. Here is my JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/6n4kugbp/

HTML

```
<input id="id_name" name="numid"/>
<input id="id_age" name="price"/>
<button id="add_btn">click</button>

<table border="1" class="mytab"></table>
```

Jquery

```
$("#add_btn").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#id_numid').val(), 
        age = $('#id_price').val();

    $('<tr><td>'+numid+'</td><td>'+price+'</td></tr>').appendTo( $('.mytab') );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not misunderstanding to your question, you can try this:

---

**UPDATE:**

I've update the code for auto sort while appending new row. You can change default sort order column by configuring `defaultSortColIndex` value.

```js
$(function() {
  var defaultSortColIndex = 0;
  
  function sortTheTable() {
    var table = $('table');
    
    $('th')
      .wrapInner('<span title="sort this column"/>')
      .each(function() {
        var th = $(this),
          thIndex = th.index(),
          inverse = false;

        th.click(function() {
          table.find('td').filter(function() {
            return $(this).index() === thIndex;
          }).sortElements(function(a, b) {
            return $.text([a]) > $.text([b]) ?
              inverse ? -1 : 1 :
              inverse ? 1 : -1;
          }, function() {
            return this.parentNode;
          });

          inverse = !inverse;
        });
      });
    
    $('th').eq(defaultSortColIndex).trigger('click');
  };

  $('button#add_btn').on('click', function() {
    var sName = $('input#name').val();
    var sAge = $('input#age').val();

    if (isNaN(sAge)) {
      alert('Invalid age number.');
      return;
    }

    var sTr = '<tr>';
    sTr += '<td>' + sName + '</td>';
    sTr += '<td>' + sAge + '</td>';
    sTr += '</tr>';

    $('table').append(sTr);

    sortTheTable();
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.orderable {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/sortElements/jquery.sortElements.js"></script>

<input id="name" name="name"/>
<input id="age" name="age" />
<button id="add_btn">Add</button>

<table border="1" class="mytab">
  <tr>
    <th id="name" class="orderable">Name</th>
    <th id="age" class="orderable">Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$("#add_btn").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var name = $('#id_numid').val(), 
    age = $('#id_price').val();
$('<tr><td>'+numid+'</td><td>'+price+'</td></tr>').appendTo( $('.mytab') );
sortTable($('.mytab'), "asc");
});

function sortTable(table, order) {
var asc   = order === 'asc',
    tbody = table.find('tbody');

tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (asc) {
        return $('td:first', a).text().localeCompare($('td:first', b).text());
    } else {
        return $('td:first', b).text().localeCompare($('td:first', a).text());
    }
}).appendTo(tbody);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - hope it helps as I understand you are looking to sort table data by age in ascending order then below code works.

using `.sort()` method.

if you are looking to sort by name 
then just replace

```
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.age - b.age;
  });
```

to

```
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
     if(a.name < b.name ) return -1;
     if(a.name > b.name ) return 1;
     return 0;
  });
```

```js
var data = [];

$("#add_btn").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $('#id_name').val(),
    age = $('#id_age').val();

  var array = {
    "name": name,
    "age": age
  };

  data.push(array);

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.age - b.age;
  });

  $('.mytab').html('');
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('<tr><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.age + '</td></tr>').appendTo($('.mytab'));
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id_name" name="name" placeholder="Enter a name here..." />
<input id="id_age" name="age" placeholder="Enter age here..." />
<button id="add_btn">Add</button>
<hr/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="mytab"></tbody>
</table>
```